# I put Excel data in Oracle. but Oracle data with different values ​from Excel

Tags: oracle

input:

[image]
(more)
[image]

oracle result data:

[image]

how to insert: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWIhGWXEZC4)

My Oracle version : 12.2.0.1

Why is this happening?

Comment: data type : varchar2(150), varchar2(150), varchar2(150), number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel stores numbers using [double-precision floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel). This means number accuracy is a bit vague. You're loading those numbers into strings in Oracle, and it looks like Oracle is materializing the floating point vagueness.

The likely solution would be to use Oracle columns defined with NUMBER datatype, preferably with the expected precision e.g. `number(15,2)`.

It's good practice to store data in the correct datatype (numeric data in NUMBER, dates in DATE, etc) so why do anything else?

Comment: I resolved the number data type problem. thank you.
and Can I add one more question?
1.3 /10 =0.13
why is the data coming out at 1.2999 ...?
and I must use to do VARCHAR2, but I do not know what to do.